# Form processing in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I started studying the Zend_Form component and understand most aspects of it. I know how to add form elements and set configuration options for them, how to apply form decorators, how to add validators and filters... But today i got stuck on the processing of those forms.

There's one particular thing that just baffles me. I'll illustrate it with an example which i kept as simple as possible.

First we create the form as a separate class. Nothing special here, just a username and password field and a submit button. We'll also add a label and some filters and validators to them.

```
class Login_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setaction('/user/login')
             ->setMethod('post');

        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $username->setLabel('Username:')
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->addFilter('StringToLower')
                 ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $password->setLabel('Password:')
                 ->setRequired(true);

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setValue('Submit');

        $this->addElements(array(
            $username,
            $password,
            $submit
            ));

        return $this;  
    }
}
```

Next we'll create a 'user' action controller with a 'login' action method. Here, i want to check if the form got submitted (if not it should be displayed) and validate it. Notice the two identical lines of code. Although the $form object did not change in the mean time, the first produces no output, the second does.

```
class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $form = new Login_Form;

        // Check if form got submitted
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            // This does not produce output
            echo 'Username: ' . $form->getValue('username');

            if ($form->isValid($_POST))
            {
                // This does produce output (same line of code as above)
                echo 'Username: ' . $form->getValue('username');
            }
            else
            {
                echo $form;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo $form;
        }
    }
}
```

If i would just want the unfiltered values, I could get them from the request object with `$this->getRequest()->getPost()`. I want the filtered values though (the filters are defined in the Login_Form class) so I should get them from the form object with `getValues()`. I find it awfully strange that the $form object changes after calling `isValid()` on it (which just returns a boolean and does not alter the $form object). Any help with this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how the Zend_Form object works: You need to pass the actual data that was submitted into it, it does not grab it from somewhere itself. This is because the source of data can vary. One application always uses POST, someone wants to validate GET parameters as well, and a completely different application doesn't even have HTTP requests, but does want to validate input from the commandline.

I wonder why your code seems to work. First, your form doesn't even define a method - will fail for sure. Second, in your controller I would expect $form->getValue('username') to work, but the access to a property should not work - I do not see any code inside the Zend_Form source that sets public properties.

Comment: The form does define a method, you'll notice at the top of the Login_Form class that I use setMethod() for this. I also changed the line of code that accessed the form element as a property. It now uses $form->getValue('username'). Still, I don't see why this only produces output after I called isValid() on the form.

Comment: Ok, you fixed the code errors. :) Apart from that: The values are only available after a call to `isValid()` because that is the only way the form can know about the values. You have to use it like this, it is by design.

Comment: I see where I got it wrong and it's clear to me why akond's answer below is working. However, I took a look at the Zend_Form::isValid() method and as far as I can see it does not alter the form object in any way...

Comment: `Zend_Form::isValid()` calls the `Zend_Form_Element::isValid()` of every element. There the first command is: `Zend_Form_Element::setValue()` - so the element stores the value it is about to validate. After that all form elements know their current value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the filtered values like so:

```
$filtered_values = $form->getValidValues ($_POST);
```